# How to set Multi Layer Check in Altium 14?

Tags: altium

When defining component clearance in Altium it warns you when 2 components are too close, but, it also warns you even when the components are on different layers so obviously they can't collide.

As described [here](http://videos.altium.com/trainingcenter/player.html?ep=1029) you can use `Multi Layer Check` for collision checking:

[image]

But in Altium 14.1 I don't see this option:

[image]

Where is this option located now? I can't find it anywhere! I even tried using `Query` to try to get this behavior but it didn't work.

Here for example I get a warning between Multi-Layer and Top Overlay on the same component!

[image]

Comment: Glad my answer got it done for you, but this is DEFINITELY not right... if those two pieces belong to the same COMPONENT, they should never fail a component clearance check.

Comment: Do you know why this could be happening?

Comment: Not... really.... There's a little voodoo going on to determine component outline when there's no 3D body to work from.... so you might just try to plop a 3d body into the component (just a rectangle around the component outline), then update the PCB file with the modified component as a test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't gotten really familiar with AD 14 yet, but you could just write two rules, Top_Clearance and Bottom_Clearance.

Top clearance has
Where The First Object Matches: Layer Top

Where The Second Object Matches: Layer Top

Bottom_Clearance is similar. Although I've never seen a clearance check problem between two LAYERS. If I remember correctly, this is how AD 10 works too. Maybe you need to define some more accurate/realistic 3D bodies? Or maybe I don't fully understand your problem.

Comment: It worked! This is an issue I had in Altium 10 too and for example, Altium also complained about clearance between multi-layer pads and Top Overlay on the same component! See my edited question.